# Lost validation and autocomplete when upgrading to February release

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems something is wrong with my installation (osx 10.11.3) but I can't determine why and i'm not sure how it worked prior to the February release of vs code.

For example:

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express();
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
//Some code
}
```

if I replace app.post with app.FOO it won't signal that there is an error and that foo is unknown. Also I don't get auto complete for 'post' after app.
Furthermore I don't get any light bulb that would allow to download the definitions from typescript to get auto  complete.
What could cause this issue ?

(this is for Vs CODE, not standard vs)

Edit: also noticed this: when on a js file, when I change file type to let's say CSS, it will show all the errors of course because it's not a CSS file. When I revert back file type to js.... it will still show the errors of CSS ??!! I think this is a bug in the latest update. See attached image.

[image]

---

Edit: I manually added in project root a jsonfing.json file with:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

and I added a 'typings' folder in project root, with node, pg and express typings files.

Comment: Do you have typings installed? There should be folder 'typings' in the project root. Also do you have jsconfig.json?

Comment: Please see updated answer, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What OS are you on, also please try to "Reload Javascript Project" (ctrl+shift+p).

Comment: OSX El Capitain. Reload doesn't work. It seems javascript validation is completely disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue it seems vscode team has removed the quick fix for type definitions in the release. We have to add the d.ts using below plugin

https://github.com/typings/typings

once you installed the typings for the library you wanted, you need to create a jsconfig.json file. Steps below

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

[note: i left this file empty]

Now the vs automatically loads the d.ts files if it is under typings directory

Below is the issue that I created in Github

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3867

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was able to reproduce this bug, seems like now you have to set up project with *jsconfig.json* and explicitly add excluded folders. Example *jsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Also don't forget to "Reload Javascript Project".

More details https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3901 and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3791

Comment: Thanks it helps. I now have auto complete... for example when I type 'app.' it suggests "post" from the choices. But when I modify already existing code like 'app.poXXXXst" it doesn't detect a problem. Shouldn't it ? Shouldn't there be an underline to point there is problem with poXXXXst ? Seems there is autocomplete, but NO code validation on existing code. I did reload Js code project from the command palette and even restarted the ide.

Comment: Another problem I just noticed: 'app.' will propose 'post' in autocomplete, ONLY if I type NEW code. Only then will it propose it on already existing code. This is very weird. So if i restart ide and type 'app.p'  it will not propose 'post' in auto complete. But if I add a new line with 'app.p' it will propose 'post' auto complete on this new line, and now also in existing line which wasn't the case a few seconds ago.

Comment: Try to remove node_modules and install again.